# Приведите пример из жизни чтобы можно было оценить вероятность 2^-128

Tags: алгоритм, веб-программирование, математика

Т.е. насколько 2^-128 невероятно? Это как 100 раз подбросить монетку орлом? Или как выиграть в лоттерею?

Comment: Нет, это как 340 282 366 920 938 463 463 374 607 431 768 211 456 раз подбросить монетку

Comment: @Mike Вообще-то на самом деле как раз 128 раз. А насколько невероятно? Смотря с чем сравнивать :) Давненько мне попалась статейка, так что могу ошибаться - но там была оценка, что при вероятности несчастного случая 10^-6 (или 10^-4... вот тут точно не помню) человек чувствует себя абсолютно спокойно. Здесь же порядок 10^-39 :)

Comment: @Mike, вы как-то перегнули. При одном броске вероятность выпадания орла 1/2, при двух бросках вероятность выпадания двух орлов - 1/4, при n бросках вероятность выпадания n орлов - 1/(2^n). Т.е. при 128 бросках вероятность того, что выпадут все орлы как раз 1/(2^128) = 2^(-128)

Comment: @АндрейNOP приведенное мной число и есть 2^128. А на счет что подбросить для этого монетку 128 раз надо и ожидать определенного исхода, я с Harry согласен. тут перегнул, не так сформулировал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Представьте, что у вас есть некий пароль длиной 32 символа. Добавим ограничение: пароль должен содержать только цифры и буквы от A до F. Такой пароль можно записать в шестнадцатеричном виде и тогда у нас получается ровно 16 байт. Злоумышленник хочет отгадать ваш пароль. Вероятность того, что найдет пароль - это  1/16^32 == > 1/ 2^(4^32) == > 2^-128.

Предположим, что наш злоумышленник может генерировать один миллиард паролей в секунду. Чтобы иметь 50%-ный шанс угадать, нашему злоумышленнику пришлось бы сгенерировать 2^127 паролей. При скорости генерации в один миллиард в секунду, для генерации 2^127 паролей потребуется всего лишь 5 391 448 762 278 159 040 348 лет. Насколько это много? Возраст существования вселенной, около 13 799 000 000 лет.

Comment: Я бы ещё добавил, что возраст вселенной составляет всего-то 13 799 000 000 лет.